# Two prototype cells in one section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two prototype cells. One appears if `messagesArray[indexPath.row]` value is "", the other if that value contains characters. One of the cells' row height is greater than the second and contains additional variables. They're both hooked up to their own cell classes and have their own cell identifiers. I want them both to coexist in the same tableview, under one section, but I'm struggling to achieve that. I keep getting `fatal error: Array index out of range`. The array value is being populated from an async DB request, which could be the explanation.

What am I doing wrong/how can I do this successfully?

```
var messagesArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

var query = PFQuery(className: "Class")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        if let message = object["message"] as? String {
                            self.messagesArray.append(message)
                        }
                    }

                }


         } else {
                    println(error)
                }
         }
   }



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if self.messagesArray[indexPath.row] == "" {

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellOne

            return cell

        } else {

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTwo

            return cell
        }


    }
```

EDIT: If `messagesArray[indexPath.row] ==` some value other than `""` (there's actually a message), then that first cell in which the message is displayed in will be larger than the second cell and be displayed by a `UILabel` that doesn't exist in second cell.

Comment: are you trying to query from parse and load the tableview? and also are you using static cell or dynamic

Comment: Yes and both dynamic

Answer (score 0):

if you are using dynamic cells you must not have two prototype cells on your tableView, only one is needed to get the job done.

```
var messagesArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       var query = PFQuery(className: "Class")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
               if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
               {
                   for object in objects
                   {
                    var message = object["message"]
                    self.messagesArray.append(message)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            }


        }

        else
        {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellOne

         var data = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]
           cell.textlabel.text = data
```

}

Comment: but still when you are using dynamic cell you cannot have two cell ... so if your array only has 2 values ... your tableview will display 2 values etc..

Comment: But I need to have two different sized cells in the same table view. How can I change the rowHeight of each cell?